# How to clean untracked or ignored files when containing several .gitignore

Tags: git, emacs, elpa

Platform: Windows 8.1

To simplify Emacs configuration, I upload my Emacs personal folder `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d` to github.

Usually I use Emacs 24.3 to edit the `init.el` file, after which a copy named `init.el~` is created under the same folder. With the help of `.gitignore` I add a line `*~` to `git clean -fdx` the trailing slash file.

The problem is the `elpa` package like `AucTeX` which owns a self-contained `.gitignore` file. This file might contain pattern to remove `*.elc` file that I want to retain. So there are several `.gitignore` files under my repository. One is created by my self. The others are for `elpa` packages.

If I try to `git clean -fdx`, the `AucTeX`'s `.gitignore` file will come into effect by removing the `*.elc` file under the repository.

How can I disable the `.gitignore` file that is not created by me?

How to deactivate the `.gitignore` files attached other Emacs `elpa` packages?

Comment: .gitignore file is present in the root directories, in your case AucTex directory. Search for this file and simply delete it. Add and commit. .gitignore will stop tracking now, because it's not there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confused about the git clean arguments? The `-x` argument tells git clean to *pay no attention* to the contents of `.gitignore` files (so that *all* untracked files are removed). The `.elc` files aren't being removed *because* they're listed in the AucTeX's .gitignore file; they're being removed because they're *untracked files*, and because you've told git not to treat .gitignored files as protected.

If you commit the `.elc` files (which are [portable](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3418/454)), git won't want to clean them.

Personally, I always do that. I don't want to be running with uncompiled code, and I don't want the bother of recompiling everything unnecessarily. The chances of encountering a portability problem are very slim -- and if you ever did run into problems and wanted to recompile a library, it's much simpler to do if there are existing `.elc` files to tell Emacs which files *should* be compiled.

Add https://github.com/tarsius/auto-compile into the mix, and your `.elc` files will always be present and up-to-date.

If you don't want to do that, then I guess you'll either need to run git clean without the `-x` argument and deal with the file patterns from your root-level .gitignore in an additional pass; or else use the `--dry-run` argument to show what it would delete, and filter out the files you want to actually keep (in which case you might do a first pass without `-x` and then a second pass with `-X` (upper-case) which you would filter).

Comment: I have tried both `git clean -ndx` and `git clean -ndX`. They both will clean all the `.elc` file. You mentioned in your post `.elc` files are **untracked files**. I think this is the case. I did commit and push the `.elc` file to github web  repository.